# How to pass label inside a label to another view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

I have a view, which consist of a label that changes dynamically.How can I put the text in the label into an array and then pass it to another view controller?

Comment: Which part are you stuck on exactly?  Have you ever used a table view before?  Can you provide more details about "changes dynamically" means?

Comment: @nhgrif yes I have. Am what you might call a novice in iOS developing as I only started developing recently. To expand my knowledge and sharping my skills more am developing a QRScanner app and I have 2 views (e.g. View A & B).  In view A I have successfully done the QRScanning part and I store the QR scanned details(e.g. website links, names, numbers) in a label. In view B I have a blank table view I want to be able to populate the cells in the tableView with the scanned details stored in the label of view A.Am sucked on what to do to populate the table view cells with the data from the label

Comment: When you've used table view's before, how have you populated data in them?

Comment: @nhgrif using tuples and manually adding them using alertController I have never tired anything this broad

Comment: If you are new to iOS programming I recommend you follow the course `Developing iOS 8 Apps in Swift` in iTunesU. There are older versions of this course that use Objective-C. The course will teach you how to do this and teach you about other frameworks in iOS as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a data structure like NSDictionary or NSArray , and save the details of your View A into it. Then when your view B is called , pass these values to View B and use it to populate your TableView

example in swift

- ViewController Class

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var label1 = UILabel()
var label2 = UILabel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

func updateLabels()
{

    label1.text = "LABEL 1"
    label2.text = "LABEL 2"
}


///If you are using Xibs

@IBAction func loadTableViewController()
{
    // Create a data structure for the data you want to send
    var array : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    array.addObject(label1.text!)
    array.addObject(label2.text!)


     // Create a viewcontroller  instance of tableViewController
    let viewcontroller = tableViewController(nibName:"tableViewController",bundle:nil)

    viewcontroller.dataSourceArray = array


}

//// If you are using Story Board
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    // Create a data structure for the data you want to send
    var array : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    array.addObject(label1.text!)
    array.addObject(label2.text!)

    // Create a new variable to store the instance of tableViewController
    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! tableViewController


    destinationVC.dataSourceArray = array
}
```

- Tableviewcontroller class

class tableViewController: UITableViewController 
{

```
@IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!
var dataSourceArray : NSMutableArray!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // dataSourceArray will contain the label details passed from previous view controller.


}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    // you can set the details from the dataSourceArray

}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // you can set the details from the dataSourceArray
}
```

Comment: Can you please give an example on how to that? thanks

Comment: check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Well your question is not so clear but as i can predict is, you are navigating from the label view to table view and want to show all those values of label in tableview.
You can achieve this by putting all the values of those labels in a mutable array and in the table view controller, make a property of type NSMutableArray. and at time of navigation, put the array of labels view to the property of table view controller.
You can see the below code for reference.

Label View Controller

```
@interface DummyViewController (){
    NSMutableArray *array;
}

@end

@implementation DummyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue"]) {

        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:label1.text,label2.text,label3.text nil];

        FinalTableViewController *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view"];
        view.dataArray = array;
    }

}
```

In table view controller

.h file

```
@interface DummyViewController : UIViewController

     @property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *dataArray;

@end
```

Now use this data array in table view delegate methods to fill data.
If you found answer useful please don't forget to make the green tick.

Comment: the above code is in objective C am looking for how to to it in swift

Comment: I was just giving you a basic knowledge regarding how you can implement this,
All you have to is to change the above code in swift syntax